# Prebuilt node-sass for alpine linux not used

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, node-sass

As I understand `node-sass` packages has a prebuilt binary for Alpine Linux as noted on [releases page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) but for some reason when I run `yarn install` it tries to compile it from the source.

What could be the reason for that? Is this a yarn bug?

```
yarn install v1.5.1
warning package.json: No license field
warning emulsify@1.0.0: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "/var/www/html/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c node scripts/build.js
Directory: /var/www/html/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/html/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/var/www/html/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@9.11.1 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing \"build\" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable \"python2\" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

Comment: Its looking for python whether its installed via checking in PATH variable in installation.

Comment: it's looking for python because it tries to compile it but I don't get why there's a need for the compilation in the first place

Comment: What version are you trying to install? Node 9 is only supported with 4.8.3

Comment: @nschonni I use Node 8.11

Comment: It says 9.11.1 in your log above. Maybe you're running NVM or another version switcher that is changing the version of Node

Comment: @nschonni you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the answer since a hidden comment isn't good enough for most people :

uninstall NPM and reinstall v8.11, nvm may have upgraded it.